# Drawing repeating image behind Divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var sketcher = null;
var brush = null;

function Sketcher(canvasID, brushImage) {
    this.renderFunction = (brushImage == null || brushImage == undefined) ? this.updateCanvasByLine : this.updateCanvasByBrush;
    this.brush = brushImage;
    this.touchSupported = Modernizr.touch;
    this.canvasID = canvasID;
    this.canvas = $("#" + canvasID);
    this.context = this.canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
    this.context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    this.context.lineWidth = 3;
    this.lastMousePoint = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    if (this.touchSupported) {
        this.mouseDownEvent = "touchstart";
        this.mouseMoveEvent = "touchmove";
        this.mouseUpEvent = "touchend";
    } else {
        this.mouseDownEvent = "mousedown";
        this.mouseMoveEvent = "mousemove";
        this.mouseUpEvent = "mouseup";
    }
    this.canvas.bind(this.mouseMoveEvent, this.onCanvasMouseMove());
}

Sketcher.prototype.onCanvasMouseMove = function() {
    var self = this;
    return function(event) {
        self.mouseMoveHandler = self.onCanvasMouseMove()
        self.mouseUpHandler = self.onCanvasMouseUp()
        $(document).bind(self.mouseMoveEvent, self.mouseMoveHandler);
        $(document).bind(self.mouseUpEvent, self.mouseUpHandler);
        self.updateMousePosition(event);
        self.renderFunction(event);
    }
}

Sketcher.prototype.onCanvasMouseMove = function() {
    var self = this;
    return function(event) {
        self.renderFunction(event);
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}

Sketcher.prototype.onCanvasMouseUp = function(event) {
    var self = this;
    return function(event) {
        $(document).unbind(self.mouseMoveEvent, self.mouseMoveHandler);
        $(document).unbind(self.mouseUpEvent, self.mouseUpHandler);
        self.mouseMoveHandler = null;
        self.mouseUpHandler = null;
    }
}

Sketcher.prototype.updateMousePosition = function(event) {
    var target;
    if (this.touchSupported) {
        target = event.originalEvent.touches[0]
    } else {
        target = event;
    }
    var offset = this.canvas.offset();
    this.lastMousePoint.x = target.pageX - offset.left;
    this.lastMousePoint.y = target.pageY - offset.top;
}

Sketcher.prototype.updateCanvasByLine = function(event) {
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.moveTo(this.lastMousePoint.x, this.lastMousePoint.y);
    this.updateMousePosition(event);
    this.context.lineTo(this.lastMousePoint.x, this.lastMousePoint.y);
    this.context.stroke();
}

Sketcher.prototype.updateCanvasByBrush = function(event) {
    var halfBrushW = this.brush.width / 2;
    var halfBrushH = this.brush.height / 2;
    var start = {
        x: this.lastMousePoint.x,
        y: this.lastMousePoint.y
    };
    this.updateMousePosition(event);
    var end = {
        x: this.lastMousePoint.x,
        y: this.lastMousePoint.y
    };
    var distance = parseInt(Trig.distanceBetween2Points(start, end));
    var angle = Trig.angleBetween2Points(start, end);
    var x, y;
    for (var z = 0;
        (z <= distance || z == 0); z++) {
        x = start.x + (Math.sin(angle) * z) - halfBrushW;
        y = start.y + (Math.cos(angle) * z) - halfBrushH;
        //console.log( x, y, angle, z );
        this.context.drawImage(this.brush, x, y);
    }
}

Sketcher.prototype.toString = function() {
    var dataString = this.canvas.get(0).toDataURL("image/png");
    var index = dataString.indexOf(",") + 1;
    dataString = dataString.substring(index);
    return dataString;
}

Sketcher.prototype.toDataURL = function() {
    var dataString = this.canvas.get(0).toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataString;
}

var Trig = {
 distanceBetween2Points: function ( point1, point2 ) {
  
  var dx = point2.x - point1.x;
  var dy = point2.y - point1.y;
  return Math.sqrt( Math.pow( dx, 2 ) + Math.pow( dy, 2 ) ); 
 },
 
 angleBetween2Points: function ( point1, point2 ) {
 
  var dx = point2.x - point1.x;
  var dy = point2.y - point1.y; 
  return Math.atan2( dx, dy );
 }
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("sketch");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
brush = new Image();
brush.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/440px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg";
brush.onload = function() {
    sketcher = new Sketcher("sketch", brush);
};
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sketch-container {
    position: relative;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

#sketch {
    background: none yellow;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.button-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    opacity: .5;
    background: none blue;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<div class="sketch-container">
    <canvas id="sketch"></canvas>
    <button type="button" class="button-container">Can you draw below me?</button>
</div>
```

I am drawing an image using this javascript code:

```
var sketcher = null;
var brush = null;

function Sketcher(canvasID, brushImage) {
    this.renderFunction = (brushImage == null || brushImage == undefined) ? this.updateCanvasByLine : this.updateCanvasByBrush;
    this.brush = brushImage;
    this.touchSupported = Modernizr.touch;
    this.canvasID = canvasID;
    this.canvas = $("#" + canvasID);
    this.context = this.canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
    this.context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    this.context.lineWidth = 3;
    this.lastMousePoint = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    if (this.touchSupported) {
        this.mouseDownEvent = "touchstart";
        this.mouseMoveEvent = "touchmove";
        this.mouseUpEvent = "touchend";
    } else {
        this.mouseDownEvent = "mousedown";
        this.mouseMoveEvent = "mousemove";
        this.mouseUpEvent = "mouseup";
    }
    this.canvas.bind(this.mouseMoveEvent, this.onCanvasMouseMove());
}

Sketcher.prototype.onCanvasMouseMove = function() {
    var self = this;
    return function(event) {
        self.mouseMoveHandler = self.onCanvasMouseMove()
        self.mouseUpHandler = self.onCanvasMouseUp()
        $(document).bind(self.mouseMoveEvent, self.mouseMoveHandler);
        $(document).bind(self.mouseUpEvent, self.mouseUpHandler);
        self.updateMousePosition(event);
        self.renderFunction(event);
    }
}

Sketcher.prototype.onCanvasMouseMove = function() {
    var self = this;
    return function(event) {
        self.renderFunction(event);
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}

Sketcher.prototype.onCanvasMouseUp = function(event) {
    var self = this;
    return function(event) {
        $(document).unbind(self.mouseMoveEvent, self.mouseMoveHandler);
        $(document).unbind(self.mouseUpEvent, self.mouseUpHandler);
        self.mouseMoveHandler = null;
        self.mouseUpHandler = null;
    }
}

Sketcher.prototype.updateMousePosition = function(event) {
    var target;
    if (this.touchSupported) {
        target = event.originalEvent.touches[0]
    } else {
        target = event;
    }
    var offset = this.canvas.offset();
    this.lastMousePoint.x = target.pageX - offset.left;
    this.lastMousePoint.y = target.pageY - offset.top;
}

Sketcher.prototype.updateCanvasByLine = function(event) {
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.moveTo(this.lastMousePoint.x, this.lastMousePoint.y);
    this.updateMousePosition(event);
    this.context.lineTo(this.lastMousePoint.x, this.lastMousePoint.y);
    this.context.stroke();
}

Sketcher.prototype.updateCanvasByBrush = function(event) {
    var halfBrushW = this.brush.width / 2;
    var halfBrushH = this.brush.height / 2;
    var start = {
        x: this.lastMousePoint.x,
        y: this.lastMousePoint.y
    };
    this.updateMousePosition(event);
    var end = {
        x: this.lastMousePoint.x,
        y: this.lastMousePoint.y
    };
    var distance = parseInt(Trig.distanceBetween2Points(start, end));
    var angle = Trig.angleBetween2Points(start, end);
    var x, y;
    for (var z = 0;
        (z <= distance || z == 0); z++) {
        x = start.x + (Math.sin(angle) * z) - halfBrushW;
        y = start.y + (Math.cos(angle) * z) - halfBrushH;
        //console.log( x, y, angle, z );
        this.context.drawImage(this.brush, x, y);
    }
}

Sketcher.prototype.toString = function() {
    var dataString = this.canvas.get(0).toDataURL("image/png");
    var index = dataString.indexOf(",") + 1;
    dataString = dataString.substring(index);
    return dataString;
}

Sketcher.prototype.toDataURL = function() {
    var dataString = this.canvas.get(0).toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataString;
}

var Trig = {
    distanceBetween2Points: function ( point1, point2 ) {

        var dx = point2.x - point1.x;
        var dy = point2.y - point1.y;
        return Math.sqrt( Math.pow( dx, 2 ) + Math.pow( dy, 2 ) );  
    },

    angleBetween2Points: function ( point1, point2 ) {

        var dx = point2.x - point1.x;
        var dy = point2.y - point1.y;   
        return Math.atan2( dx, dy );
    }
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("sketch");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
brush = new Image();
brush.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/440px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg";
brush.onload = function() {
    sketcher = new Sketcher("sketch", brush);
};
```

It works well and draws an image exactly as I would like. However, I have divs on top with text for which I have onclick functions on.

[Picture of how the image is being drawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXngx.png)

The problem is the image is not being drawn underneath the divs because the canvas is under them. I understand I may need to add a listener to the window and draw according to that, but I have tried and tried and do not understand where something like that goes/what needs to be replaced.

Something that I've tried is to get rid of pointer events, which of course works to maintain the continuity of the image being dragged, but prevents me from clicking on the button.

Thanks

Comment: its hard to debug if you do not provide all the code..

Comment: Hi Iliya, can you try to create a working Fiddle? I've started one for you, you can [continue here](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/784ocs5q/11/)... for example there is an error, `Trig` is undefined. Please make it work, than update.

Comment: Yep, updated, I forgot to include part of the javascript and about to also update the question. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/45p16tqz/2/

Comment: @skobaljic Please rather encourage askers to use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) so that the code ends up on Stack Overflow, where everyone can see and run it. Many people who could help are blocked from jsFiddle. See also [ask] and [mre].

Comment: I've added a Snippet as well. Thanks Heretic Monkey and Skobaljic for the recommendations.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It was already created and it was not running and I did not want to add a broken snippet to the question. I just wonder, why would anyone be blocked from jsFiddle? Can you please elaborate/explain?

Comment: So no luck with this question then?

Comment: Hate to bump this back up, but after months of trying can still not get this to work.